# Code design to make adding similar tasks later easy

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

For example I have a app that can download videos. Since the tasks for downloading are similar I create a base class for downloading.

```
public abstract class Download {
  public abstract void run();
}
```

For each concrete website, where videos can be downloaded I create a child class from the base class:

```
public class DownloadYouTube extends Download {
  public void run() {
  }
}

public class DownloadVimeo() extends Download {
  public void run() {
  }
}
```

To see from which site the user wants to download I create a enum and switch through it to create the right object, then I call the common method run().

```
public enum WEBSITE {
  YOUTUBE,
  VIMEO
}

public void startDownload(WEBSITE website) {
  Download download;
  switch (website) {
    case YOUTUBE:
      download = new DownloadYoutube();
      break;
    case VIMEO:
      download = new DownloadVimeo();
      break;
  }
  download.run();
}
```

Later other people may want to add new websites. With that design it is not to easy. People have to edit on three places: They have to alter the enum, they have to add a new case and they have to write the class itself.

It would be way better if the had just to write the class.

Is there any common code design or other advise to handle such a situation better than this?

Comment: Use a Dependency Injection framework, such as Spring, to create the concrete `Download` instances, and inject them into the code that needs to call them.

Comment: For a simplest (bit not cleanest) approach, set up a naming scheme, and use `Class.forName()` to load classes based on the video service name, the way DB drivers do.

Comment: @9000 That's not type-safe, which is what people generally look for when using `enum`. Easier approach yeah, but it's also easier to mess up with a typo or assuming a type is supported when it isn't.

Comment: Is a new object needed every time startDownload is called? Either way, my answer helps get rid of the enum, allowing you to use downloaders by doing nothing more than creating a new class :)

Comment: @VinceEmigh: It's typesafe (`String` is a type as good as an enum), it's just not enforceable statically at compile time. This depends on whether you want static enforcement at compile time, or maybe dynamic discovery at deploy / run time.

Comment: You can see the  `Item 30: Use enums instead of int constants` in `Effective Java`,it say *there is a better way to associate a different behavior with each enumconstant: declare an abstract apply method in the enum type, and override it witha concrete method for each constant in a constant-specific class body.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a map! A map is a data structure that lets you look up any sort of value with a key, so an instance of each of your download classes can be accessed by providing a string. (your variable 'website' can turn into this)

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;


    Map<String, Download> downloaders = new HashMap<String, Download>();

    downloaders.put("Youtube", new DownloadYoutube());
    downloaders.put("Vimeo", new DownloadVimeo());


    // Iterate over all downloaders, using the keySet method.
    for(String key: downloaders.keySet())
        Download d = downloaders.get(key)
    System.out.println();
```

NOTE: If you intend to use multiple instances of the same Download class, this solution will not work as posted here.

Comment: Simple and great idea. This also works perfect with command line arguments.

Answer (score 3):

As a possible solution you can add an abstract factory method to your enum which would create a necessary `Download` object.
So `WEBSITE` becomes not just a list of websites you support, but also encapsulates behaviour for each of them:

```
public enum WEBSITE {
    YOUTUBE {
        @Override
        public Download createDownload() {
            return new DownloadYouTube();
        }
    },
    VIMEO {
        @Override
        public Download createDownload() {
            return new DownloadVimeo();
        }
    };

    public abstract Download createDownload(); 
}

public void startDownload(WEBSITE website) {
    website.createDownload().run();
}
```

With such an approach it will be impossible to add a new `WEBSITE` without defining how it should be handled.

Comment: And in addition to that you don't need `Download` to be an abstract class, an interface is enough

Answer (score 0):

> It would be way better if the had just to write the class.

You can use [*class literals*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/literals.html) as opposed to enums:

```
startDownload(DownloadYouTube.class);
```

Simply have `startDownload` accept a `Class<T extends Download>` and instantiate it:

```
public void startDownload(Class<T extends Download> type) {
    try {
        Download download = type.newInstance();
        download.run();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStacktrace();
    }
}
```

Now all you have to do is create a new class that extends/implements `Download`

```
class DownloadYouTube extends/implements Download {

}
```

---

`Download` should be an `interface` if it only consists of `public abstract` methods:

```
interface Download {
    void run();
}

class DownloadYouTube implements Download {
    //...
}
```

The `startDownload` method above would stay the same regardless.

---

`WEBSITE` should actually be `Website`. Type identifiers should start with an uppercase and use camel casing standards:

```
enum Website { }
```

Although an `enum` is not needed for my solution above.

---

You should check to see if you really need a new instance every call. It seems you could just pass a URL to the `Download#run` if you adjusted it.

## If a new instance *isn't* needed every call:

`Website` exists for simple access to the different downloaders.

That means `YOUTUBE` should give access to `DownloadYoutube`.

You could turn `Download` into an `interface`:

```
interface Download {
    void run();
}
```

`DownloadYoutube` and `DownloadVimeo` could all implement this:

```
class DownloadYoutube implements Download {
    public void run() {
        //...
    }
}

class DownloadVimeo implements Download {
    public void run() {
        //...
    }
}
```

`Website` can also implement this:

```
enum Website implements Download {
    public final void run() {

    }
}
```

Now make it a requirement for each `Website` value to specify the `Download` to use:

```
enum Website implements Download {
    YOUTUBE(new DownloadYoutube()),
    VIMEO(new DownloadVimeo());

    private final Download download;

    Website(Download download) {
        this.download = download;
    }

    @Override
    public final void run() {
        download.run();
    }
}
```

Comment: There is a big difference with the original behaviour described in the question: now we reuse the same `Download` objects for each website.

Comment: @DmitryP. Actually, there's nothing showing there's a big difference in the behavior.. They don't show any implementation, so for all we know, those objects could be excess and the results would be the exact same, other than excess useless objects.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to decide upon has been done before.  There is a design pattern called a *Template Method*

The key idea behind a template method is that the skeleton of an algorithm is enforce, but the details fall upon subclasses.  You have a

```
public interface DownloadTask {
    public List<Parameter> getParameters();
    public setParameters(Map<Parameter, Object> values);
    public Future<File> performDownload();
}
```

with two concrete implementations

```
public class VimeoDownload implements DownloadTask {
  ...
}

public class YoutubeDownload implements DownloadTask {
  ...
}
```

or if you really want an enum, then

```
public enum DefaultDownload implements DownloadTask {
   YOUTUBE,
   VIMEO;
}
```

but I don't think an enum will buy you as much as you might think.  By attempting to update an enum, you must either share the methods like so

```
 public enum DefaultDownload implements DownloadTask {
   YOUTUBE,
   VIMEO;

   public void someMethod(...) {
   }
}
```

or declare them individually

public enum DefaultDownload implements DownloadTask {
       YOUTUBE() {
         public void someMethod(...) {
         }
       },
       VIMEO() {
         public void someMethod(...) {
         }
       };
    }

And both scenarios put you at risk of breaking all downloads to add one new download.

Then you have the actual template method that ties it all together

```
public class Downloader {

    /* asynchronous API */
    public File doDownload(DownloadTask task) {
        Map<Parameter, Object> paramValues = new Hashmap<>();
        List<Parameter> params = task.getParameters();
        for (Parameter param : task.getParameters()) {
            Object value = getValue(param);
            paramValues.put(param, value);
        }
        task.setParameters(paramValues);
        return task.performDownload();
    }

    /* synchronous API */
    public File doDownloadAndWait(DownloadTask task) {
        Future<File> future = doDownload(task);
        return future.get();
    }

}
```

The actual steps I provided in DownloadTask are not the ones you will likely need.  Change them to suit your needs.

Some people don't use an interface for the DownloadTask, that's fine.  You can use an abstract class, like so

```
 public abstract class DownloadTask {

     public final Future<File> doDownload() {
        this.getParameters();
        this.setParameters(...);
        return this.performDownload();
     }

     public final File doDownloadAndWait() {
        Future<File> future = this.performDownload();
        return future.get();
     }

     protected abstract List<Parameter> getParameters();

     protected abstract void setParameters(Map<Parameter, Object> values);

     protected abstract Future<File> performDownload();

 }
```

This is actually a better Object Oriented design, but one must take care.  Keep the inheritance tree shallow (one or two parents before hitting a standard Java library class) for future code maintenance.  And don't be tempted to make the template methods (doDownload and doDownloadAndWait) non-final.  After all, that's the key to this pattern, the template of operations is fixed.  Without that there's hardly a pattern to follow and stuff can become a jumbled mess.

Answer (score 0):

You are headed in the right direction...

Implementing an interface instead of extending a class will make your life easier.  Also it's kind of annoying that you have to update a enum AND modify a case statement AND write a class to add a new handler.

editing 3 places is annoying, 2 is good, 1 is awesome.

We could get yours down to 2 pretty easily:

`public enum WEBSITE {
   YOUTUBE(new DownloadYouTube()),
   VIMEO(new DownloadVimeo())
   public final Download download;
   public WEBSITE(Download dl)
   {
        download = dl;
   }
}
public void startDownload(WEBSITE website) {
    website.download.run()
}`

There now you only edit two places, the ENUM definition and the new class. The big problem with enums is that you almost always have to edit 2 places (You have to update the enum to redirect to whatever you want to edit).  In this case, the enum isn't helping you at all.

My first rule of enums is that if you don't individually address each value of the enum in a different location of your code, you shouldn't be using an enum.

You can get it down to 1 edit location, but with a new class it's pretty hard--the difficulty is that Java doesn't have "Discovery", so you can't just ask it for all the classes that implement "Download".

One way might be to use Spring and annotations.  Spring can scan classes.  Another is runtime annotation.  The worst is probably looking at the directory containing your "Download" classes and try to instantiate each one.

As is, your solution isn't bad.  2 locations is often a pretty good balance.